# Why is InputStream constructed from Channel much faster than one constructed from FileDescriptor?

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream, channel, kryo

When constructing an InputStream on a RandomAccessFile in order to have Kryo deserialize objects from it, it seems it makes a HUGE difference for performance whether one constructs the mediating InputStream through the file's Channel (gives good performance) or through its FileDescriptor (gives terrible performance):

```
RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(dataFile, "r");

Input input1 = new InputWithRandomAccessFile(Channels.newInputStream(ra.getChannel()), FILE_BUF_SIZE, ra);
Input input2 = new InputWithRandomAccessFile(new FileInputStream(ra.getFD()), FILE_BUF_SIZE, ra);
```

InputWithRandomAccessFile is my own class extending Kryo's Input class, with the only additional behavior that it seeks the correct position in the R/A file when #setPosition is called.

Reading 3,000 fixed-size objects from input1 takes around 600 ms, from input2 it takes around 16 seconds.

Comment: Most likely Kryo has been optimised for FileChannel and has to use some sort of fall back if you pass an InputStream.  Can you try `new FileInputStream(ra.getFD()).getChannel()`

Comment: Maybe strace and/or a Java profiler can give you clue.

Comment: `input2` opens a completely new, sequential access channel, while `Channel.newInputStream()` simply wraps the existing random access channel. This might be a factor.

Comment: What happens if you wrap the `FileInputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream`? I realise your class takes a buffer argument but it's not clear how this is used...

Comment: @monocell -- The buffer arg goes to the super constructor: Kryo's input class will use this to create its own buffer, which is why a BufferedInputStream is not desirable when using Kryo in this way. Just to be sure I tried what you suggested: the result was the same, around 16 seconds.

Comment: @PeterLawrey -- Kryo's Input constructor doesn't take a Channel, so what would I do with the Channel created from the stream as you suggest? I'd have to wrap it in yet another InputStream. [EDIT: I tried this anyway, and it *is* fast: 600 ms.]

Comment: @biziclop -- I think you're right. The point seems to be that the stream must be constructed on an existing Channel for the "Channel I/O" to be used. Apparently, if the stream is constructed otherwise (even from an FD for a file on which a Channel is open), it uses a much slower I/O implementation. This also explains why PeterLawrey's suggestion _did_ work.